# Full Windows Phone environment on emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I am new to Windows Phone and do not have any WP device. I've downloaded WP developer tools and was in hope to study WP in emulator as I did with Android.

But there is only Internet Explorer tile, my first application (which I couldn't find again after I exited from it) and some maps/Bingo apps. Anything else? Any settings menus? Some task manager? Or WP emulator is a very reduced variant of real cellphone which uses Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is just a simulation of the real phone, it does not provide all the functionality of a Windows phone. [Read this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_canttest) for further insights.